# Im trying to get the data entered to do calculation and display in a label

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to get The Information that is added to display in a label on the main screen. I want it to calculate the profit but i get the error " Value of type 'String' has no member 'text' "

```
@IBAction func addButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {


    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Product Information", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
     alert.addTextField(configurationHandler: { (itemTextField) -> Void in
                itemTextField.placeholder = "Item"
     })
     alert.addTextField(configurationHandler: { (priceTextField) -> Void in
                priceTextField.placeholder = "Price"
     })
    alert.addTextField(configurationHandler: { (salePriceTextField) -> Void in
             salePriceTextField.placeholder = "Sale Price"
    })



     alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Add", style: .default) { (action) in
         let item = alert.textFields?[0].text ?? ""
         let price = alert.textFields?[1].text ?? ""
         let salesPrice = alert.textFields?[2].text ?? ""

        let itemPriceLabel = Double(price.text!)
        let salePriceLabel = Double(salesPrice.text!)

        if itemPriceLabel != nil && salePriceLabel != nil {

            let profitValue = Double (itemPriceLabel! - salePriceLabel!)
            ProfitLabel.text = profitValue
        }

         let product = Product(item: item, price: price, salesPrice: salesPrice)
        self.addProduct(product)


     })

     self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
     storeData()


}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your price and salesPrice variables are already string only. But you’ve tried to access text field in those variables which is not present in String class in the next statement.

```
let itemPriceLabel = Double(price)
let salePriceLabel = Double(salesPrice)
```

And assign your value as follows.

```
ProfitLabel.text = String(profitValue)
```

Comment: how would i fix?

Comment: Replace those statements like the one in the answer I’d updated.

Comment: now i just get an error "Cannot assign value of type 'Double' to type 'String?' " at ProfitLabel.text = profitValue

Comment: Now, it's a different problem. You're trying to set profitValue which is a double as text to ProfitLabel. You should cast that as a String before setting that to profitLabel. Check the updated answer of mine.

Comment: theres no error anymore but it doesn't display the calculation in the label

Comment: Now, you should start debugging your code with Xcode. If you'd found the answer helpful do accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, both price and salesPrice are already Strings (because they took the text from the labels), not labels.
All you need to do is convert them to straight to doubles, no need for .text.

So instead of:

```
let itemPriceLabel = Double(price.text!)
let salePriceLabel = Double(salesPrice.text!)
```

Do:

```
let itemPriceLabel = Double(price)
let salePriceLabel = Double(salesPrice)
```

Comment: now i just get an error "Cannot assign value of type 'Double' to type 'String?' " at ProfitLabel.text = profitValue

Comment: For that, you need to do 
`profitValue: String = String (itemPriceLabel! - salePriceLabel!)`
or just do 
`profitLabel.text = String(profitValue)`
Basically, right now you are doing what it told you. Trying to say that a Double is a String, so all you need to do is cast it.

Comment: Also I noticed in another comment, you said the text wasn't displaying, that's because calling stuff like you did has a lot of complex stuff (that I personally barely understand), I'd recommend taking all of the code from the alert action and making it into its own function, then calling that function, as that tends to fix that sort of problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few mistakes in the alert action and the naming of the variables is confusing, replace it with

```
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Add", style: .default) { _ in
    let itemText = alert.textFields?[0].text ?? ""
    let priceText = alert.textFields?[1].text ?? ""
    let salesPriceText = alert.textFields?[2].text ?? ""

    if let price = Double(priceText),
       let salesPrice = Double(salesPriceText),
       !itemText.isEmpty {

        let profitValue = price - salesPrice
        ProfitLabel.text = String(profitValue)
        let product = Product(item: itemText, price: price, salesPrice: salesPrice)
        self.addProduct(product)
    } else {
      print("Enter something in 'item' and enter numeric values in 'price' and 'sales price'")
      // add error handling
    }
 }
```